# How to dispaly display() without deleting the other HTML

Tags: javascript

```
var students = [
  ["test", "test", "test"],
  ["test", "test", "test"]
];
students.sort();

function display() {

  for (i = 1; i < students.length + 1; i++) {
    document.write("<tr>");
    document.write("<td>" + (i) + "</td>");
    document.write("<td>" + students[i - 1][0] + "</td>");
    document.write("<td>" + students[i - 1][1] + "</td>");
    document.write("<td>" + students[i - 1][2] + "</td>");
    document.write("<td><input type='number' class='form-control' id='quiz" + i + "' ></td>");
    document.write("<td><input type='number' class='form-control' id='reqt" + i + "'></td>");
    document.write("<td><input type='number' class='form-control' id='exam" + i + "'></td>");
    document.write("<td><input type='number' class='form-control' id='pg" + i + "' readonly></td>");
    document.write("</tr>");
  }
}

function AddData() {
  var AddName;
  var AddCourse;
  var AddBDay;
  var Data;

  AddName = document.getElementById('Addname').value;
  AddCourse = document.getElementById('AddCourse').value;
  AddBDay = document.getElementById('AddBDay').value;

  if (AddName != "" && AddCourse != "" && AddBDay != "") {
    Data = [AddName, AddCourse, AddBDay];
    students.push(Data);
    console.log(students);

    display();

  } else {
    alert("Invalid Input");
  }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write` for multiple reasons: [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted any HTML, but assuming you have a `<table id="x">` or `<tbody id="x">`, modify the `display` function as below:

```
function display() {

  let html = '';
  students.map((item, i) => {
    html += "<tr>";
    html += "<td>" + (i+1) + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + item[0] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + item[1] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + item[2] + "</td>";
    html += "<td><input type='number' class='form-control' id='quiz" + i + "' ></td>";
    html += "<td><input type='number' class='form-control' id='reqt" + i + "'></td>";
    html += "<td><input type='number' class='form-control' id='exam" + i + "'></td>";
    html += "<td><input type='number' class='form-control' id='pg" + i + "' readonly></td>";
    html += "</tr>";
  });  
  document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = html;
}
```

Also, `document.write` is rarely to never used. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).
[element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is generally used when you want to perform some DOM manipulation as a result of an API call or any other event, as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` is very very old-school and it's very rarely used any more [for many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

You can either create a string variable that you can then add (concatenate) new strings to, or you can use more modern methods like in the example below which uses [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the array to create a [new array of strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) that array up into one HTML string.

```js
const students = [
  ["test", "test", "test"],
  ["test", "test", "test"]
];

function getHtml(students) {
  return students.map(arr => {
    return `
      <tr>
        <td>${arr[0]}</td>
        <td>${arr[1]}</td>
        <td>${arr[2]}</td>
      </tr>
    `
  }).join('');
}

const table = document.querySelector('table');
table.innerHTML = getHtml(students);
```

```html
<table></table>
```